# Using types defined in template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

When using a container class like `vector`, `list`, etc., I can use the type of the elements by writing `vector<type>::value_type`.

However, the following code

```
template<class container>
void foo(container& c)
{
    typedef container::value_type elementtype;
    elementtype b;
}
```

fails with the error "`expected initializer before ‘elementtype’`".
Is it possible to infer the element type when the container type is given as a template argument or do I have to give the element type as an extra template argument?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing the required typename keyword:

```
typedef typename container::value_type elementtype;
```

This is because `container` is a *dependent name* in this template, so the compiler has no way of knowing whether container::value_type is always a type or not, as it may depend on the choice of `container`.

Surely this question is a FAQ somewhere?

Edit, it is: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.18