# For a template: error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++

```
#include <list>

template < class TYPE > 
class CIndex : protected std::list < TYPE >
{
public:
    typedef std::list < TYPE >::iterator  CIndexIt;
    typedef std::list < TYPE >::difference_type  CIndexDiff;
```

The error happens in the last line of the above code.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169592/error-missing-type-specifier-int-assumed-c-does-not-support-default-int) and [the msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173696.aspx) but both don't solve my error.

Anyone knows what could be causing the problem?

**EDIT:**
The reason the first link's solution didn't work was because although adding `typename` worked for the above code, it didn't work for the below code:

```
#include<hash_map>
class CWItems
{
typedef stdext::hash_map < unsigned long, CWksItem* >   CItem;
CItem mItems;
```

So I thought I was doing the wrong thing by adding `typename` everywhere. Using `typename` after the `typedef` in this code caused this error:

```
error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration
```

Without `typename`, the error shown is `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`, at the `CItem mItems;` line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using types defined in template arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741597/using-types-defined-in-template-arguments)

Comment: Useful to have the link you posted. My problem still isn't solved though. Have edited my question to add more info. Help?

Comment: `CWItems` is not a class template so you can't have any dependent names. Where is `CWksItem` declared?

Comment: CWksItem is mentioned as `class CWksItem;` (forward declaration). But the error persists even if CWksItem is substituted with `int`.

Comment: I think the problem is something else. I wrote some standalone code for the hash_map and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `typename` keyword because `std::list<TYPE>::iterator` and `std::list<TYPE>::difference_type` are dependent names:

```
typedef typename std::list < TYPE >::iterator  CIndexIt;
typedef typename std::list < TYPE >::difference_type  CIndexDiff;
```

See http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html for more information.

Comment: The problem showed up in another part of the code, and this time `typename` didn't solve it. I've mentioned more in the edited section of my question. Help?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `typename` keyword exactly as in the question that you linked to:

```
typedef typename std::list < TYPE >::iterator  CIndexIt;
typedef typename std::list < TYPE >::difference_type  CIndexDiff;
```